# How to save results from dynamic cascading drop down list?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 cascading drop down list , when page loads, data is loaded to the 1st DDL, when  item is selected from this list its goes to the database and fetch matching items and populate 2nd DDL. I want to prevent going twice to the DB on selection.
For example, I am loading 1st DDL with cars manufactures then click on Toyota what happens next is it goes to DB and fetches all Toyota's models and populates the 2nd DDL, after that i select different car manufacture, same thing happens. Now when i select again Toyota from the 1st list it will not go to DB, it will pull the data from previous request.

I will like to keep an object (like dictionary) of the requests, so if item is already been requested it will not go back to the DB but use local saved data.

Comment: Caching already exists in HTTP. I’d maybe rather leverage that, than create my own client-side JavaScript cache …

Comment: And on top of HTTP cache enabled strategy, I'd also save the data in memory, so that for the duration of the lifetime of the page, you wouldn't need to issue multiple HTTP requests for the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can store list return from server through LocalStorage in Javascript. By using setItem()function as shown below.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('Toyota', 'Models');
```

Where Toyota is the key and Models is the value. Also note that LocalStorage can only store strings.

To store arrays or objects you would have to convert them to strings.

To do this we use the JSON.stringify() method before passing to setItem() .

```
const models = {
1: "Model-1",
2: "Model-2",
}
window.localStorage.setItem('Toyota', JSON.stringify(models));
```

Now when ever you select different car manufacture check its value in LocalStorage object first.

It accepts only one parameter which is the key and returns the value as a string.

To retrieve the Toyota key stored above:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('Toyota');
```

This returns a string with value as.

```
“{“1”:”Model-1”,”2”:”Model-2”}”
```

To use this value, you would have convert it back to an object.

To do this, we make use of JSON.parse() method which converts a JSON string into a Javascript Object.

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Toyota'));
```

Please keep in mind to check weather your browser support Local storage or not.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Code for localStorage
} else {
  // No web storage Support.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map() object to store the data based on key.
Find more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

```
var brandModelsList = new Map();
function getBrandModels(brand)
{
    if(brandModelsList.has(brand))
    {
        modelList =  JSON.parse(brandModelsList.get(brand));
        // Do stuff with second dropdown
    }
    //Your ajax stuff to get data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server url',
        data: {name: brand},
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(response => { 
        brandModelsList.set(brand, JSON.stringify(response));
        // Do stuff with second dropdown
    });
}
```

It has support in most of modern browsers. A best tutorial on this is https://javascript.info/map-set-weakmap-weakset.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via JavaScript as @Rahat Hameed stated if the cascading dropdown values are not changed frequently, if they can be changed e.g (you can updated them via some logic).Then preferable ways it to fetch them from database.